# Desired resolution of images for a Beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, graphics, presentations, resolution

I am working on a Beamer presentation for less-technically-inclined audience, so I want to use many visual aids, pictures, stock photos, etc.  Unfortunately, these are mostly raster images, not vector diagrams.

From your experience, what minimal resolution is required so that an image would not appear pixelated when covering a full slide?  I particularly refer to projecting the presentation from a beamer, not viewing it on a computer screen.

Comment: It depends on the resolution and the distance of your *projector*. Note that *beamer* is a pseudo-English term from Germany (where the author of the `beamer` class is from). I, also German, made the experience that in English it is the nick-name for an BMW, which made my request "to borrow a beamer for my presentation tomorrow" a little awkward.

Comment: Since that I don't know the resolution of the projector in advance, I am asking for general tried-and-tested rules-of-thumb.

Comment: While it isn't the *minimal* resolution you asked about: you could just go with HD resolution, i.e. 1920×1080, to be on the save side. Note that your audience wont see pixels from a projected presentation from 2m distance anyway, so if it looks good on screen it should be more then fine.

Comment: @Martin: +1 for the funny story.  Is there a nickname for BMW in German?

Comment: @Matthew: No, there isn't because the German pronunciation is already very short: *Be-eM-We* (where 'e' is the German 'e', which is difficult to explain right here)

Comment: @Martin: I suspected that very thing.  The big difference is the *W*, whose name is simple in German and ugly in English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do beamer presentations with lots of art.  While I have not experimented to find minimum values, I get good results from anything 1024x768 pixels and up.  This is flickr's "large" size.

I mention flickr because it's a good resource for this kind of thing.  Do an advanced search and check the box for Creative Commons-licensed photos.

In case you want to keep looking for vector art, try these:

- [Free Vector Resources For Designers in 2011](http://webification.com/free-vector-resources-designers-websites-2011) Showed up in my tweetstream the other day; lists many sites.  I don't know what the licensing is for these.
- [openclipart.org](http://openclipart.org) has only public-domain works.  You can even search this site within InkScape to make your own modifications.

Answer (score 5):

In my experience, most projectors have a resolution of 1024x768 px (XGA), and there are still plenty around that only have 800x600 px (SVGA).

So if your images have 1024x768 px, you should be fine, and if the images are photos (no text and no sharp lines), scaling up from 800x600 px would probably also work (try looking at [this 800x600 px image](http://www.bsimracing.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/02/bmw-m3_race_version_2009_800x600_wallpaper_01.jpg) in fullscreen mode on a standard 1024x768 px screen).